# L2TP / IPsec VPN on Mikrotik

Tags: networking, vpn

could you please help me finding a solution for my VPN? I've setup VPN on my mikrotik router in the office and it is working just fine. So I've done same setup for my clients mikrotik and my elemenentary OS could not connect. Settings are perfectly same. VPN to my office is working but not to my client.

The problem is that is not working only on my laptop with elementary OS, Windows and iOS is working...

Comment: See this: [how to install open VPN](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Q6-43ucVh44)

Answer (score 1):

First Network Manager by default doesn't support L2TP, So first install network-manager-l2tp, Use below steps.

```
sudo apt install git intltool libtool network-manager-dev libnm-util-dev libnm-glib-dev libnm-glib-vpn-dev libnm-gtk-dev libnm-dev libnma-dev ppp-dev libdbus-glib-1-dev libsecret-1-dev libgtk-3-dev libglib2.0-dev xl2tpd strongswan libnss3-dev
```

Issue the following on the command-line (note: the backslash character \ is the shell line continuation character which can safely be copy and pasted):

```
git clone https://github.com/nm-l2tp/network-manager-l2tp.git
cd network-manager-l2tp
autoreconf -fi
intltoolize

./configure \
  --disable-static --prefix=/usr \
  --sysconfdir=/etc --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu \
  --libexecdir=/usr/lib/NetworkManager \
  --localstatedir=/var \
  --with-pppd-plugin-dir=/usr/lib/pppd/2.4.7

make
sudo make install
```

Then try to match the encryption info with your windows system where it's working fine, If still doesn't work please post logs here.